# Run functions for all occurrences of content in string enclosed in square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, textarea, match, contains

I have a string. The data is from a text area and contains occurrences of (varying) content enclosed in square brackets.

I would like to run functions (e.g. replace) on the string content that is enclosed in square brackets, then update the original string to reflect the changes made.

Example

`not this [potentially act on this token] not this [potentially act on this token] not this`

I think some of the following may be involved but I can’t figure out how to implement a working solution. I wouldn’t like to use jQuery or external libraries.

- Match + RegEx [Something like this](http://regexr.com/3a188).
- indexOf. Possibly to get the content of the match if it can’t be done with RegEx alone.
- For each. As there are numerous instances of content enclosed in square brackets.

Here’s a starting point [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gregabbott/fdtxvyo7/3/).

If anyone could be of any assistance, I’d really appreciate it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "run functions on"? Explain

Comment: It can easily be done with `replace` since it accept a callback function as replacement param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your jsfiidle has pretty much all you need, except that the replace function can take a callback. This callback receives one parameter which is the matched string and whatever you return is substituted for the match

```
user_input = user_input.replace(/\[.*\]/gi,function(match){
    return match + "foo";   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fdtxvyo7/6/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ...

```
var startEnd = user_input.match( /(\[.*?\])/g );
```

`startend` is now an array of the bracketed values that you can now use for search/replace.

Comment: This should come in handy for something else I’ve been wanting to do. Thank you very much @rfornal!